# Android custom round button

Tags: android

I want to have a Button/ImageButton that looks like this (round button on the left)

[image]

What are my choices? Can I draw it using a shape? or is it better to use a png icon for that? ideas? What I want to do is to be able to display a new activity when the button is clicked/touched.

Comment: Use a png image in your `ImageButton`..Thats all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

```
android.R.drawable.expander_ic_minimized
```

look into built in android drawables:

http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/